# How to check which rows and columns of a matrix changed sign

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Suppose I have two matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Assume that there is a way to change the signs of rows and columns of $A$ such that the resulting matrix is equal to $B$. In other words, assume that there exist diagonal matrices $D_1, D_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that:

$$D_1AD_2 = B$$

where the diagonal entries of $D_1$ and $D_2$ are $\pm 1$.

Then **is there an (efficient) algorithm to determine which rows and columns of $A$ changed sign to equal $B$?**

Perhaps, some information could be retrieved from the entry-wise product of the $\pm 1$-sign matrix of $A$ and $B$, though I am not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that works if $A,B$ have no zero entries. Let $M$ denote the matrix whose entries satisfy
$$
m_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & \operatorname{sgn}(A_{ij}) = \operatorname{sgn}(B_{ij})\\
-1 & \operatorname{sgn}(A_{ij}) \neq \operatorname{sgn}(B_{ij})
\end{cases}
$$
where sgn denotes the sign (AKA signum) function. Note that
$$
D_1AD_2 = A \odot D_1(ee^T)D_2
$$
where $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product and $e = (1,\dots,1)^T$. With that, we see that we're looking for matrices $D_1,D_2$ such that $D_1(ee^T)D_2 = M$.

We are given that such matrices $D_1,D_2$ exist, which means that $M$ is necessarily of rank $1$.  It follows that $M$ can be written in the form $uv^T$. Because all entries of $M$ are equal to $\pm 1$, we can take $u,v$ to be matrices whose entries are $1$ or $-1$.

From there, we see that $u = \operatorname{diag}(u)$ and $v = \operatorname{diag}(v)$, which means that we can simply take $D_1 = \operatorname{diag}(u)$ and $D_2 = \operatorname{diag}(v)$.